# Does not return result - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a table where in the result site returns a value but for now nothing appears. I really appreciate your help.

```
<tr>
<th>Objetivo 1</th>
<th>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input id="DataInicio" type = "date" class = "datepicker" name = "DataInicio" />
        <label for="datainicio"></label>
    </div>
</th>
<th>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input id="DataFim" type = "date" class = "datepicker" name = "DataFim" />
        <label for="datafim"></label>
    </div>
</th>
<th>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input id="avInicial1" type="text" class="validate"
               autocomplete="off" name="AvInicial"
               onchange="calculaResultado(1)">
         <label for="avinicial"></label>
    </div>
</th>
<th>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input id="meta1" type="text" class="validate" autocomplete="off"
               name="Meta" onchange="calculaResultado(1)">
        <label for="meta"></label>
    </div>
</th>
<th>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input id="AvIntercalar" type="text" class="validate"
               autocomplete="off" name="AvIntercalar">
        <label for="avintercalar"></label>
    </div>
</th>
<th>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input id="avFinal1" type="text" class="validate"
               autocomplete="off" name="Avfinal" onchange="calculaResultado(1)">
        <label for="avfinal"></label>       
    </div>
</th>
<th>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input disabled id="resultado1"/>
    </div>
</th>
```

```
<script>

(function calculaResultado(x){

console.log(x);
a = document.getElementById('avInicial' + x).value;
b = document.getElementById('meta' + x).value;
c = document.getElementById('avFinal' + x).value;

const resultado = ((c*100)/b);

  if(b === c){
    return 1; //100%
  } else if (a > c) {
    return 0; // 0%
  } else {
    return resultado;
  }

document.getElementById('resultado' + x).value =  parseInt(resultado); 
})();
```

When I run and enter the values nothing happens in the result column.

Comment: try to use https://jsfiddle.net/ to post an example of your code running - ou pergunte no https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have an error of logic in your javascript function calculaResultado.

You seem to be checking and returning a value and your code will never reach the line for:

```
    document.getElementById('resultado' + x).value =  parseInt(resultado);
```

The offending code is this block:

```
    if(b === c){
        return 1; //100%
    } else if (a > c) {
        return 0; // 0%
    } else {
        return resultado;
    }
```

I would advice changing the block to something like this:

```
    let resultado = ((c*100)/b);

    if(b === c){
        resultado =  1; //100%
    } else if (a > c) {
        resultado = 0; // 0%
    } else {
        resultado = parseInt(resultado);
    }

    document.getElementById('resultado' + x).value = resultado;
```

Comment: Are you saying that your field is not updating??? Where do you include the script for the function, in the header or at the closing body tag? You should also remove the '(' before the 'function' and remove ')();' at the end of the function. The script should be placed before your closing body tag.

Comment: What happens is that there is no value in the results column. I am performing the script at the bottom of the page but inside the body.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. Eternally grateful, I was already going crazy

Comment: @user9822783 if this answer your question, mark it as the answer.

Comment: @user9822783 can you please mark it as the answer, thanks so much.